# e^-x MacLaurin Series Expansion

Tags: c, series

I am trying to compute the MacLaurin series for e<sup>-x</sup> = 1 - x + (x<sup>2</sup> / 2!) - (x<sup>3</sup> / 3!) +...

My values seem to work up to a certain point and then deviate completely. Is there something wrong with rounding or am I using the wrong type of variable for such a question?

```
int i;
double sum=0;
double x = 8.3;

for(i=0; i<26; i++)
{
    sum = sum+ (((pow(-1,i)) * (pow(x,i)))/factorial(i));
    printf("Sum = %.12f\n\n\n",sum);
}

return 0;
```

I don't understand why, but up to the 12th term, the values are correct but after that, it begins to completely differ.

Comment: Because `12!` is 479e6 which fits into a 32 bit `int`, and `13!` is 6.2e9, which exceeds the range of a 32 bit `int`. How are you computing the `factorial`?

Comment: int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n<=1)
        return(1);
    else
        n=n*factorial(n-1);
    return(n);
}

Comment: Should I make my return value and input value into doubles?

Comment: Yes, that would help, but even better would be to do the calculation incrementally. The terms are `1`, `-x`, `x^2 / 2!`, etc. So if you know the previous term, you can compute the next term in the series by multiplying by `-x` and dividing by `i`. That way you don't have to keep calling the `pow` and `factorial` functions.

Comment: If you care to do so, you could probably speed up the loop storing a sign variable and toggling it every iteration instead of computing pow(-1,i) to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your `factorial` function, which you're not showing, is performing integer arithmetic. After 12! you're going to overflow a 32-bit integer. Switch to using `double` in the `factorial` function too.

Comment: This was going to be my guess too.  beat me to it.